# How to get the input and textarea values on change function using jquery

Tags: jquery

$('#filedset').find("select, input, textarea").change(function() {
                    alert($(this).val());
                });

if I use this code when I change anything on my dropdownlistbox I am getting alert but when I change anything on my Input or textarea changed text i am getting on alert?

is that something i am doing wrong?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `change` events for these fire when they lose focus normally (e.g. click outside), if you want the handler to execute as you type, I recommend using the [`.keyup()`](http://api.jquery.com/keyup/) event instead (so you get the right value, `keydown` would be the value *without* the current key taken into account).

Like this:

```
$('#filedset').find('select, input, textarea').bind('change keyup', function() {
   alert($(this).val());
});
```

Or if you have lots of and/or dynamic elements, you can use [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/), like this:

```
$('#filedset').delegate('select, input, textarea','change keyup', function() {
   alert($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: This is not working for me I am not getting alert with any value change

Comment: @rockers - Here's a short demo: http://jsfiddle.net/6X5d5/1/ Are you sure your selector is right, did you mean `$("fieldset")`, looking for `<fieldset>`, or are you actually looking for `id="filedset"`?